# Adding Max to a Result After Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running the following SQL Server query which gives me what I want below.

```
SELECT company,
       benefit,
       avg(perVal) AS P,
       VAR(perVal) AS V
FROM Percept_Responses
GROUP BY company,
         benefit
```

| company | benefit | P | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 1 | Benefit 1 | 5.5 | 0.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 3 | Benefit 1 | 7.5 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 1 | Benefit 2 | 4.5 | 0.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 3 | Benefit 2 | 6 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

But now I would like to add the maximum P value for each benefit... so an extra row for each benefit with the maximum P value.

| company | benefit | P | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 1 | Benefit 1 | 5.5 | 0.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 3 | Benefit 1 | 7.5 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Max | Benefit 1 | 7.5 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 1 | Benefit 2 | 4.5 | 0.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| Competitor 3 | Benefit 2 | 6 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max | Benefit 2 | 6 | 0 |

I imagine this could be done in one SQL query. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `where group by` likely returns an error

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: ok..I deleted the images.

Comment: sorry, I had a group by in my original code and just took it out since it's irrelevant to the questions...thanks.

Comment: It seems that a subquery might help, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47400833/924299).

Comment: We still want to see sample data and expected results, just as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Stuff your current query into a CTE, select all rows from the cte and then union that with a query that applies MAX to the CTE.

Comment: Thanks SMor. Any chance you could show me how this is done?

Comment: Basic syntax is:  with cte as (<your current query>) select ... from cte union all select null, benefit, max(P), null from cte group by ... You will need to add ordering logic but it is better to get a working query first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can construct the result set using `union all`.  The subquery in the outer `select` makes it easier to ensure the final ordering:

```
with cte as (
      select company, benefit, avg(perVal) AS P, var(perVal) AS V
      from Percept_Responses
      group by company, benefit
     )
select company, benefit, p, v
from ((select company, benefit, p, v, 1 as ord
       from cte
      ) union all
      (select 'Max', benefit, max(p), 0, 2 as ord
       from cte
       group by benefit
      )
     ) cb
order by benefit, ord;
```